# Sending notifications only when user enables it

Tags: android, notifications, settings

I have a ToggleButton in my app, where users can turn the notifications ON nad OFF. I managed to create a class, where the state of the button is saved, so even after closing the app, the last selected state is showing:

```
public class SetFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_set, container, false);

    ToggleButton toggle = view.findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch);
    toggle.setChecked(readState());


    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Log.e("aaaaa","checked");
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                Log.e("aaaaa","not checked");
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
            saveState(isChecked);
        }
    });



    return view;
}


private void saveState(boolean isFavourite) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("State", isFavourite).apply();
}
private boolean readState() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("State", true);
}
}
```

Now the problem is, how to send notifications only to those users, who has this option enabled in the app? Now I can send the notifications to all users.

I think if check the `readState` in my `MyFirebaseMessagingServiceclass`, and if it is true then do `sendNotification` otherwise do nothing.

Am I thinking the right way?

Comment: Yes, You are thinking the right way!

Comment: well I created it, works fine, but it only works when the app is running. When the apop is in background, then a default notification is crating not handled by sendNotification. Can I handle this case somehow? For now I used:   if (readState()) {sendNotification(title, message); }

Comment: Unfortunately if you are using Firebase Console for sending notifications this then your logic will not work if the the app is in background and if you are using your server thats good then send data messages and everything will be okay! Using firebase console if the app is not running then firebase sdk will display the notifications itself and none of your logic will work! Your logic will be called only if the app is running.... USE A SERVER, its not too hard! Do you have knowledge in servers and http ( or xmpp) requests?

Comment: Yesh, it was suggested to me to use something like https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
} but not sure where to put this code. I tried also to use Postman to run this code, but it works not. I don't want to send this only to one device, so the "to" parameter shouldn't be a token I suppose. However in this case how can I check, if the user has enabled or disabled the notifications?

Comment: Yeah surely you should do that! It will work fine! I also made an app with that feature and its in playstore! You can customize more to allow user selection like mine! Some wanted the phone to vibrate when notification comes, some did not want the sound or vibrations, some did not even want the notifications themselves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I can confirm this is the easiest solution. When turned ON button, I used FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("NEWS"); when turned OFF, I used unsubscribe. Then via Postman I am sending notification and also DATA to the topics (so I don't need to wait untill the topic appears in Firebase console). I tested it, works fine. When I turn on - the notifications comes, turned off, not comes. Thanks to everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

## If you are using your own server for push notification.

Best way to send push notification to Enable Users is Call API to maintain flag in server side. And From server, you can send Push Notification only those users who have enable push from device. So you no need to handle anything in Android Device side.

## If you are using Firebase Dashboard for push notification.

You have to maintain push locally either you have to show push or not.
But best suggestion is to maintain it from your server side.

Comment: I'd like to use the server side, but really not sure how. How to check via API if they have enabled it or not.

Comment: @wotan you can use topic messages for that. If a person has not subscribe or he she unsubscribed! Its automatic!

Comment: So is this a good logic ? When user switch the notify button to ON, he subscribes to Topic, when switch off, unsubscribe from Topic. Then I can send the notify via Firebase to Topic to all users, who are subscribed to Topic. If this will work, then I'd rather go this way. Now just I need to figure out, how to subscribe or unsubscribe to Topic onchange the button.

Comment: When user Turn ON, Call API to subscribe particular user. When user Turn OFF, Call API to unsubscribe particular user. So From server side, Just get all user's token who are subscribe and send notification so only subscribe users will get Notifications. So it's easy as compare with locally handle.

Comment: and what if I use FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("NEWS"); when the users turn ON and unsubscribe when turn OFF? If this will work, I think this is the easiest way to send to all subscribed users with Firebase. However, not sure if this will work, I will wait some hours untill the topic will be created.